# Authentic using plain password while connecting to Jboss 7.1.1Final server from remote client, How to encrypte the credential?

Tags: java, encryption, jboss, jboss7.x

In my JNDI Lookup i have connecting to Jboss 7.1.1Final from remote client with plain text password working fine.

Now i am trying to make my credentials in the form encryption, is not working.

```
#=======================================================================
#             JNDI Configuration For EJB3.1
#=======================================================================

org.mycom.user.server.j2ee.UserSHome=myproj/myproj-user-server-j2ee//User!org.mycom.user.server.j2ee.UserSHome

java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true

java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
```

**without Encryption:**

```
java.naming.security.principal=user1

java.naming.security.credentials=pwduser1
```

**with Encryption:**

```
java.naming.security.principal=user1

java.naming.security.credentials=73437d00520f1768fcd97a2074c95be9
```

**Encryption logic from:**

```
<%JBOSS-HOME%>/standalone/configuration/application-users.properties
```

Please help to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have the same problem. I need to store my LDAP admin password on the [ldap.properties](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/blob/master/dcm4chee-arc-assembly/src/main/resources/configuration/dcm4chee-arc/ldap.properties) file, as stated [here](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4chee-arc-light/wiki/Installation#setup-wildfly), assigned to `java.naming.security.credentials`. That problem seems to have no solution. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/527360/1657502

Comment: Did either of you manage to figure out a solution to this?